# SQL Server 2012 - Stuff function for concatenating string of values

Tags: sql-server-2012

I would like to return two string columns using `STUFF` to concatenate a list of values. But will I group by a column which is NULL the string column also then returns NULL, I want it to return the list when the is NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE #Vendors
(
    vendor varchar(50),
    rate INT,
    client varchar(10),
    part_no varchar(15)
);

INSERT INTO #Vendors
(JERRY, NULL, CLIENT1, 112233),
(JERRY, NULL, CLIENT2, 112234),
(JERRY, '', CLIENT1, 112235),
(JERRY, '', CLIENT2, 112236),
(JERRY, '', CLIENT3, 112237),
(JERRY, 8, CLIENT2, 112238),
(JERRY, 8, CLIENT2, 112239),
(JERRY, 8, CLIENT3, 112240),

select 
    vendor, rate,
    stuff((select ',' + CAST(st2.client as varchar(10))
           from stock st2 
           where st.vendor = st2.vendor 
             and isnull(st.rate, '') = isnull(st2.rate, '')
           group by st2.client
           for xml path('')), 1, 1,'') as clients, 
    stuff((select ',' + CAST(st2.part_no as varchar(10))
           from stock st2 
           where st.vendor = st2.vendor 
             and isnull(st.rate, '') = isnull(st2.rate, '')
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as part_no
from 
    stock st (nolock)
where 
    vendor = 'JERRY'
group by 
    vendor, rate
order by 
    vendor, rate
```

This is what is returned:

```
vendor       rate                   client                             part_no
------------ --------------------   --------------------------------   -----------------------------------------------
JERRY        NULL                   CLIENT1,CLIENT2,CLIENT3            112233,112234,112235,112236,112237
JERRY                               CLIENT1,CLIENT2,CLIENT3            112233,112234,112235,112236,112237
JERRY        8                      CLIENT2,CLIENT3                    112238,112239,112240
```

The Vendor and rate is correct, but the client and part_no is showing the same for rate is NULL and ''.

How do I return this, a part_no can't be appearing more than once:

```
vendor       rate                   client                             part_no
------------ --------------------   --------------------------------   -----------------------------------------------
JERRY        NULL                   CLIENT1,CLIENT2                    112233,112234
JERRY                               CLIENT1,CLIENT2,CLIENT3            112235,112236,112237
JERRY        8                      CLIENT2,CLIENT3                    112238,112239,112240
```

If I remove the isnull from isnull(st.rate, '') = isnull(st2.rate, '')

I get this:

```
 vendor      rate                   client                             part_no
------------ --------------------   --------------------------------   -----------------------------------------------
JERRY        NULL                   NULL                               NULL
JERRY                               CLIENT1,CLIENT2,CLIENT3            112235,112236,112237
JERRY        8                      CLIENT2,CLIENT3                    112238,112239,112240
```

Thanks.

Comment: nice work on sample data,but stock table is missing.this statement also needs more clarity "Vendor and upc_code is correct, but the acccount and code is showing the same for upc_code NULL and ''."